# Force applied in a body moving at high speed

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces

Consider a rod of length $l$ and uniform density is moving at high speed. I want to deflect the rod where should I need to apply the minimum force, so that the rod is deflected..?

Comment: The further the rod from the destination the easier to deflect. E.g a rod 1cm from hitting its target will need more force to move it completely to the left than if it was a mile back and you tapped it slightly. like on a circle, 1 degree at the center of the circle is barely noticeable, but if you draw those lines out 1 degree apart from a mile, the end points are much further away from eachother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is centroid of the rod which is at $l/2$ from both ends.

Answer (score 2):

The centre of mass of the rod is at the midpoint of the rod.  Any force applied which is parallel to the velocity of the rod will not deflect it but will change its speed.  If you apply to force anywhere other than the centre of mass, you are applying a torque and the rod will gain rotational momentum.  This means some of your force is being wasted rotating the rod, rather than changing the velocity.

So with that in mind, I think the answer must be to apply the force at the centre of mass (so nothing is wasted in rotation) and normal to the initial velocity of the rod (maximum deflection).